# Why do I get UserControl Eventhandler definiton error?

Tags: c#, events, user-controls

I have custom button (UserControl) and I want to create an event handler for parent form but I always get this error and I don´t know why:

UserControl:

```
public event EventHandler OnMyClick;
private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (OnMyClick != null)
  OnMyClick("test",e);
}
```

Parent form:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 CreateMainMenu();
 Computers_List ctrl = new Computers_List();
 ctrl.OnMyClick += MainMenuClicked(); //I get error here on OnMyClick
}

protected void MainMenuClicked()
{
//something       
}
```

Error:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'Computers_List' does not contain a definition for 'OnMyClick' and no extension method 'OnMyClick' accepting a first argument of type 'Computers_List' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) IT sklad    C:\Users\somap\onedrive\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\IT sklad\IT sklad\Form1.cs    27  Active

Comment: Can you post the definition for `Computers_List`? From the error it seem to think that there is no `OnMyClick` property.

Comment: Hmm, a usercontrol.  No, wait it is a button control.  No, wait, it is a list control.  No, wait, it is a menu control.  Erm, what the heck is it?  Well, not what you think it is.  You need somebody to review your code, ask a team member or friend.

Comment: @HansPassant what? I said it is usercontrol

Comment: @Bassie why do I need a property?

Comment: @Somachr Well you don't have to have one, but if you want to call `Computers_List.OnMyClick`, then the `Computers_List` object needs to have a property/field/event called `OnMyClick`. Based on the error you posted, it seems that (and I quote) `'Computers_List' does not contain a definition for 'OnMyClick'`. Since you haven't posted the code for `Computers_List`, how can we know whether `OnMyClick` actually exists? Looking at the `UserControl` docs, I can see that this object also doesn't contain `OnMyClick`. So does `Computers_List` contain a member called `OnMyClick`?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the [EventHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx) definition expects a method which takes two parameters (`object`, `System.EventArgs`), and has `void` return type. What you provide however, has no parameters. You should just change your  `MainMenuClicked` method to take two parameters of type (`object`, `System.EventArgs`), i.e `protected void MainMenuClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Comment: You should also remove the () on the line you are getting the error. You don't want to invoke the method, you just want to take the reference of it. Another syntax for what you want to accomplish is like this;
`ctrl.OnMyClick += new EventHandler(MainMenuClicked);`